# Using printf with threads and socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I was making a server using socket programming that echoes what the client says to him. But when I print out the message(send by client) and it's length, the message and it's length don't match. I am using printf to print.

What I basically want is to close the connection when the client types "exit". But strcmp("exit",clientmessage) is not working.

server code:

```
//for running type ./a.out anyportnumber
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *function(void *s)
{
    int s1;
    int n;
    char rmsg[500];
    s1 = *(int *)s;
    while((n = read(s1,rmsg,499)) > 0) {
        rmsg[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s %d\n",rmsg,strlen(rmsg));
        bzero(rmsg,499);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int arrc,char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int s1,len;
    int s2;
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int port;
    pthread_t t1;
    char message[500];
    port = atoi(argv[1]);
    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(s1 == -1) {
        perror("socket not created\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("socket not binded\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(listen(s1,5) == -1) {
        perror("unable to listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,function,(void *)&s2);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    close(s2);
    close(s1);
    return 0;

}
```

client side input:

```
shivam@shivam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ telnet localhost 8009
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hhh
jhiklmnop
```

Server side output:

```
shivam@shivam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Study/chat$ ./a.out 8009
hhh
 5
jhiklmnop
 11
```

Edited code:

```
//for running type ./a.out anyportnumber
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *function(void *s)
{
    int s1;
    int n;
    char rmsg[500];
    s1 = *(int *)s;
    char d[] = {'e','x','i','t','\0'};
    while((n = read(s1,rmsg,499)) > 0) {
        rmsg[n-2] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(d,rmsg) == 0) {
            write(s1,"bye",3);
            close(s1);
        }
        rmsg[n-2] = '\n';
        rmsg[n-1] = '\0';
        write(s1,rmsg,strlen(rmsg));
        bzero(rmsg,499);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int arrc,char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int s1,len;
    int s2;
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int port;
    pthread_t t1;
    char message[500];
    port = atoi(argv[1]);
    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(s1 == -1) {
        perror("socket not created\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("socket not binded\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(listen(s1,5) == -1) {
        perror("unable to listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,function,(void *)&s2);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    close(s2);
    close(s1);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, there are no message boundaries.  So you cannot write application logic that depends on the return value of `read()` as you are doing.

Workarounds for this are length-prefixed strings, or sending the NUL terminator through the socket.  You can dream up other mechanisms too, but the client must, within the data stream, tell the server where the message ends; the TCP layer won't do that.

Comment: There are even special ascii values for this (*normally used in serial terminals, but still useful and used*). I once worked with a device that would use them. STX (0x02) to start text, and I think it was 0x03 to end text. So the OP could use those *unused* ascii values for that too. I am working currently with a websocket server that sends lists of Json separated with such characters and also uses the STX.

Comment: Of course, I know. I actually don't really understand why it is done like that. It's a service on the web that is not documented or anything and I simply infered the way things are sent or received to/from it, to work with it. But it is indeed wierd. Since you can define arrays in pure Json so no need for any separators or special characters. But that is the way it works.

Comment: @BenVoigt Have a look at the edited code. It is working fine after I removed  last two characters. Will this work all the time?

Comment: @ShivamMitra: No, it won't be reliable.  A single command such as `exit` could be split across multiple read calls (e.g. you get `e` from the first and then `xit\r\n` from the second -- this is really bad because now index `n-2` where you write the NUL character is negative and you corrupt another object) or you could get more than one command in a single read call like `hello\r\nexit\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the characters the user is typing in, you're also getting a carriage return (0xd) and linefeed (0xa) character when the user presses the Enter key.  That's why you're getting a number 2 larger than you might expect.